# When using IIS Windows authentication, MVC and [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")], is this a domain administrator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

This might be a stupid question but i seem unable to find the exact result to my query.

When using IIS windows authentication, together with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` (or admin/administrators/etc), does this refer to the domain (IE domain administrator) OR is this group a part of your website and thus needs implementation?

In other words, I have a MVC website, a part is anonymous, a part authenticated and a part only for domain admins. I have tried configuring it using IIS but couldnt get it to work and using attributes no luck either (anonymous and nonanonymous work, but the admin part is either nonanonymous or doesn't pass at all)

Answer (score 0):

use: 
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]

and yes

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When the prompt pops up, i log in as an admin, but it doesn't accept it. However, i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it from here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx)

[Authorize(Roles = "[Domain]\Domain Admins")]